# how can firewall/iptables check incoming tcp traffic of already bound ports?

Tags: sockets, tcp, port, firewall, iptables

As far as i know only one process can be bound to a port of the same protocol, and in order to read incoming information to a port a socket must be bound to a that relevant port.
is there a way of sharing a socket with another process or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way of sharing a socket with another process or something like that?

Sharing a socket and thus the port between two processes is possible (like after fork) but this is probably not what you want for data analysis, since if one process reads the data the other does not get them anymore.

> how can firewall/iptables check incoming tcp traffic of already bound ports?

Packet filter like iptables work inside the kernel and get the data before they gets send to the socket. It does not even matter if there is socket bound to this specific port at all. Unless the packet filter denies the data they get forwarded unchanged to the socket (if there is any).

Passive IDS like snort or tools like tcpdump get the raw packets and here it also does not matter if there is a socket at all. They can only read the packets, i.e. not modify or block.

Application level firewalls or (reverse) proxies have their own socket and receive the data there (directly or redirected by the packet filter). They can then analyse the data and will explicitly forward the data (maybe after modification) to the original application.

Comment: if iptables can access packets ignoring the port i assume it does this by using some library that provides layer 2 API (i mean if it doesnt listen to a specific port it probably listens to specific mac address or something of that sort) , do you know which library is it?

Comment: Packet filter like iptables work at a different level. They do not listen for anything, they are just in the path of packet processing and get the packets before any socket processing etc is done by the kernel.